# Getting a strange error with grunt-contrib-compass after upgrading to Yosemite

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, rbenv

I am getting this strange error now with grunt-contrib-compass after upgrading to yosemitie. I am using bundler with rbenv. Any ideas anyone? The gem_path location doesn't even exist on my system so I am not sure how the plugin is generating the path location.

```
Warning: Command failed: /Users/amchang/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:315:in `to_specs': Could not find 'compass' (>= 0) among 8 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/amchang/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/gemsets/system-gemset', execute `gem env` for more information
        from /Users/amchang/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
        from /Users/amchang/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:58:in `gem'
        from /Users/amchang/.rbenv/versions/2.1.4/bin/compass:22:in `<main>'
     Use --force to continue.
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sass', '3.4.6'
gem 'sass-globbing'
gem 'compass', '~> 1.0.1'
```

Package.json

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-nodeunit": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.4.0",
    "bower": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-bower-requirejs": "~0.4.2",
    "grunt-shell": "~0.3.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "~0.4.0",
    "assemble": "~0.4.18",
    "jsdoc": "git://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc.git",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.4.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "glob": "~3.2.6",
    "lodash": "~2.2.1",
    "grunt-notify": "~0.2.17",
    "time-grunt": "~0.2.9",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~0.4.3",
    "karma": "~0.12.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.2.1",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
    "karma-requirejs": "~0.2.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.0"
  }
}
```